# Log activity monitoring on ELK box within EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kibana, filebeat, elk

I have configured an ELK stack server with filebeat which monitors logs across several nodes within the EKS cluster on AWS.

I would like to expose the Kibana dashboard so that I can view these logs. As the machine containing ELK stack has a private IP address (no public IP), how can I expose it to outside access so that I can view it from my desktop? There were recommendations to follow, however, the 1st one and 3rd one don't work quite well, whereas 2nd one is not preferred.

1. setup ingress onto ELK machine
2. setup DNS entry to have Route 53 entry point to the IP address of ELK machine
3. port forwarding

I would appreciate some insight into a potential solution.

Comment: Is the ELK stack running in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting up port-forwarding on host machine worked for me.

`ssh -v -N -L <local port>:<elk_host>:<remote port> <jump box>`